# Decimal value of: cout << dec << boost::this_thread::get_id()

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, boost-thread

Is it possible to cout thread::id in a decimal or octal format?

```
std::cout << std::showbase;
cout << dec(or oct) << boost::this_thread::get_id()
```

I got always hex, for example 0xdf08.

Comment: I guess `get_id` returns a pointer to a thread-specific data structure. Pointers are not affected by `dec` etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to specify what output format you want by using standard I/O manipulators:

```
#include <iomanip>

// ...

std::cout << std::oct << boost::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;
//           ^^^^^^^^
//           Octal

std::cout << std::dec << boost::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;
//           ^^^^^^^^
//           Decimal

std::cout << std::hex << boost::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;
//           ^^^^^^^^
//           Hexadecimal
```

However, notice that a `thread::id` does not need to be a number. Also, it may be a number but may be printed to the standard output in a different way than just inserting that number into `std::cout`.

The C++11 Standard specification the overload of `operator <<` accepting an `std::thread::id` (which I assume to behave similarly to Boost's correspondent overload for `boost::thread::it`), says:

> [...] Inserts an **unspecified text representation** of id into `out`.

This means the representation may not be a number at all, in which case formatting manipulators such as `std::hex`,`std::dec`, or `std::oct` may not have any influence on it.

Comment: 45.3k rep and you say "you should be able to"; how about "you can"? +1 anyway.

Comment: I'd guess there's a cast missing, because `get_id()` seems to return a pointer like type or a type that has it's own output operator overloaded.

Comment: @Bathsheba: Because the Standard specification for the behavior of `std::thread:id`, which I assume to be very similar to the behavior of `boost::thread:id`, says that `operator <<` for `thread::id` "*Inserts an unspecified text representation of id into out*". So in theory it may not be a number, which means that manipulators may not affect it

Comment: @Bathsheba What exactly is your problem with the wording?

Comment: I wouldn't go as far to say "a problem" as demonstrated by my upvoting the answer. However "you should be able to" is a weaker statement than "you can". But it seems that Andy Prowl has adequately qualified his statement with his comment, so read in full means the words he chose in his answer were chosen skilfully. Another +1 if I could.

Comment: Did I miss something or is this *exactly* what the OP is already doing (as written in the question)? Therefore the *"should be able"* is indeed much more appropriate (even if it doesn't help the situation either).

Comment: @ChristianRau: I assumed the user wanted to know what are the manipulators that allows you to specify a base representation. Anyway, I will clarify the answer and add what I wrote a few comments above.

Comment: @AndyProwl *"I assumed the user wanted to know what are the manipulators that allows you to specify a base representation."* - I see, it's just that his code example already uses these (though without qualification, but so is his `cout`).

Comment: @ChristianRau: Right, it makes sense. Sometimes I rush into answering before thoroughly reading through the text. I edited the answer, thank you.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. So in Boost 1.53 x64 Win the output always give hexadecimal ID value independently of manipulators. In VS2010 in Threads window I have the same ID. 

PS: Yes, I knew about manipulators, I should have added in my post qualifications in cout and dec. I also rush sometimes -__-.